# Comparing two variables in Python not working?

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple program that compares two variables

```
from random import randint
result = (randint(1, 6))

guess = input('Guess the number: ')
if guess == result:
    print('You got it right')
else:
    print('Wrong')
    print(result)
```

The program sets the variable `result` as a random number, and then the user inputs a number that they guess. However, even when they get the number right, it says that they were wrong.

How can I get it so that when they get the correct number, it says that they are right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `guess=int(input(Guess the number : ')`

Comment: I have seen some similar questions which also have problem about variable comparing and a guess number game. Hum... so strange, why there are so many people want to make guess number game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either make INTEGER type to STRING or vice versa so that comparison can be done. Two different types (INT and STR) can not be compared.

e.g. code 01 [ both compared variables are string]

```
from random import randint
result = (randint(1, 6))

guess = input('Guess the number: ')
if guess == str(result):
    print('You got it right')
else:
    print('Wrong')
    print(result)
```

e.g. code 02 [ both compared variables are integer]

```
from random import randint
result = (randint(1, 6))

guess = input('Guess the number: ')
if int(guess) == result:
    print('You got it right')
else:
    print('Wrong')
    print(result)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! Didn't remember you could do that, this worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad to hear that. you can further add error handling, because right now if user inputs a character instead of DIGIT the program will crash.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are comparing an `int` to a `string` due to return type of `input()` being `string`. That will always give `False`.

Change your input `guess` to :

```
guess = int(input())
```

So,

```
IN : result = 5
IN : guess = 5
OUT : 'You got it right'
```

Answer (score 0):

change `guess = input('Guess the number: ')` to `guess=int(input(Guess the number : ')`

because `input()` take a string as a user input.